# converting data.frames into time series

Tags: r, dataframe, time-series, type-conversion, as.date

Here we go againi, I am still banging my head against the wall on the above problem.
I have a data.frame that I upload via csv which looks like:

```
X          SPY      VTI
01.02.2002 0.0000   0.0000
04.02.2002 -2.4578  -2.4167 
.....
31.12.2015 -1.003   -0.9685
```

where X is date and SPY and VTI are stock returns

I tried many things to convert to a time series. first I tried

```
spyvti$X <- as.Date(as.character(spyvti$X),format="%d.%m.%Y.")
```

and what I get is:

```
 X        SPY     VTI
 NA       0.0000    0.0000
 NA       -2.4856   -2.4167
 .....
 NA       -1.003   -0.9685
```

so it looks like it can't convert the first column, which is a factor, in an object of class(Date).

I tried also to detach the data.drame into 3 different vectors, converting first the date vector into character, which worked, then

```
date <- as.Date(date, format = "%d.%m.%Y.")
error in charToDate(x):
character string is not in a standard unambiguous format.
```

So I'd like to get some help with overcoming the Date problem, and I'd like to know if, when the date problem is over, creating a ts object as below is correct

```
 tsobject <- xts(date,spy)
```

where spy is a numeric.

Thanks a lot

Paolo

Comment: the format of your dates is `%d.%m.%Y`, not `%d.%m.%Y.`

Answer (score 0):

Use the "lubridate" package. It makes conversion of dates super easy.

```
library(lubridate)
dmy(spyvti$x)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am making this up from my mind. Hope it works. You can try the following:

```
  Yourdataframe$X<-strptime(as.character(Yourdataframe$X),format="%d.%m.%Y")
  Yourdataframe<-xts(Yourdataframe[,2:3],order.by=Yourdataframe[,1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your example data frame is named `df` you can convert it into a xts time series object like so:

```
library(xts)
xtsObject <- as.xts(df[,-1],order.by = as.Date(as.character(df[,1]), format = "%d.%m.%Y"))
```